# How can I make this jquery plugin(omnigrid from MooTool) work in IE 9 and Up

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mootools

Does someone know how to make this plugin "omnigrid" work in IE 9 and up.

http://www.omnisdata.com/omnigrid/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="omnigrid.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools/mootools-1.2.4-nc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools/mootools-1.2.4-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="omnigrid.js"></script>
```

Comment: when you say 'make it work' you  should typically explain what is wrong and what parts of the code are failing, this is not particularly useful to other users of the site and it won't make it easy for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is literally no need to try to get that to work when you can use SlickGrid - https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid - which is framework agnostic and tested to work well with 1 million rows.

Aside from that, you can fix it and upgrade the code to MooTools 1.4.5 but that's broken in IE11 - really need to wait for 1.5 release (soon!) before getting started.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Chirstoff. Updated the mootools-core.js to 1.4.5 and its working great. Thanks